# Are there Visual Studio Tools For Creating DTO/ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, viewmodel

I'm trying to introduce ASP.Net MVC to my department. I am encouraging them to have a ViewModel per View and AutoMapper for our larger projects (and ideally in general).

Sometimes this means having one large entity and picking 5 of its properties and creating the ViewModel. This is done by looking at the the edmx model (many projects were existing so it was DB first) and then creating matching properties in a ViewModel class. Obviously names etc have to match for AutoMapper to work. Also for navigation properties you have to add the navigation name first. Ideally also being able to type in a display name etc.

I'm trying to ease them into doing this (what they see as extra work). Is there any tool that would load a list of fields and allow you to select via checkbox etc and create the class from that?

I guess the same would apply to DTOs etc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator

you can create a template of the dto and then it will generate the files/dto's for you as needed from any kind of datasource.

Comment: Looks quite like T4 templating which I use with MVC Scaffolding. Will have a look but was hoping for something that was very straight forwad just popped up in Visual Studio and asked what fields were wanted.